# What AttributeProvider of type IListSource do?

Tags: c#, attributes, datasource, system.componentmodel

I have a user control that contains this property:

```
[AttributeProvider(typeof(IListSource))]
public object DataSource
{
  get { return _grid.DataSource; }
  set { _grid.DataSource = value; }
}
```

**How does this attribute affect the property?** (besides the pretty combo box in the designer). 
Is it forcing the property to receive only values that implement either IListSource or IEnumerable? 
Can you find me a code snippet from the BCL that explains the attribute effect?

---

Sources: 
[AttributeProviderAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.attributeproviderattribute.aspx) 
[IListSource Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf2z7b6t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) 
[How to: Apply Attributes in Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171726.aspx)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.attributeproviderattribute.aspx

Comment: Thank you, @AmiramKorach, but unfortunately not this nor [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf2z7b6t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171726.aspx) was clear enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

This attribute, as any attribute, doesn't have any effect on the attribute itself. It is only used by other components to get metadata about the property. What the documentation says is that certain components, like data binding, needs to know the type of the property. Usually this data is collected from the property attributes and the property type attributes, but here it is not possible since the DataSource property has some options what you can set for it and those types don't have anything in common except from they inherit from object, so this property tells anyone who needs to know that the type should be an IListSource.
I hope this is more clear.

Comment: It is not completely accurate to say that the type should implement IListSource. First of all if it was that simple you could just change the type of the property from `object` to `IListSource`. Second, according to [DataGrid.DataSource Property documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.datasource.aspx), that uses the exact same attribute, you can set it to any type that implements either `IList` or `IListSource`.